# slick maintain updated_at and inserted_at field

Tags: scala, orm, slick-3.0

Most of my database table models have *inserted_at* and *updated_at* timestamp fields which must be updated on creation and update events respectively. Is it possible to do this in a most DRY and transparent way in Slick. These audit columns are also not required in my Table projection (`*`) and is only used for auditing and debugging. One option was to use custom Sqltype like below.

```
  val insertedAt = column[Timestamp]("inserted_at", O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
  val updatedAt = column[Timestamp]("updated_at", O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
```

But the above code is database specific and H2 doesn't support it.

Comment: How many databases you need to support?

Comment: Ideally would prefer to have a database neutral solution.. but in my case a bare minimum of 2 (MySQL and H2)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this won't be an ideal solution, but you can however always do something like this:

```
protected def customColumn[T: TypedType](name: String, 
h2Type: SqlType, mySqlType: SqlType)
(implicit driver: BasicDriver): Rep[T] = driver match {
  case H2Driver.api.slickDriver => column[T](name, mySqlType)
  case MySQLDriver.api.slickDriver => column[T](name, h2Type)
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only MySQL and H2 profiles are supported...")
}
```

This should obviously be in some kind of your common `Table` class or some trait that you would later mix into your table definitions.

and then...

```
val insertedAt = customColumn[Timestamp]("inserted_at",
                     O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"), 
                     O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP... whatever works for MySql"))

val updatedAt = customColumn[Timestamp]("updated_at", 
                     O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"), 
                     O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP... whatever works for MySql"))
```

Far from perfect, but should do what you need in certain more complicated cases.